# Cannot find libIOKit.A.dylib in iOS 7 SDK

Tags: ios, xcode5, iphone-privateapi, iokit

I'm trying to include libIOKit.A.dylib into my project but I'm having issues finding it.

When I look in Project General/Linked Frameworks and Libraries, I don't get a result for "libIOKit.A.dylib".

What am I missing apart from the actual library?

Comment: Gabor - if that solved your problem, please accept the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its been converted into framework in 7.0. Its can be found at following location.

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit

YOu can copy this binary to some other folder and then drag and drop to "framework" folder of your project in xcode.

Btw: I was able to get almost same functions as previously. So hopefully old functionality should not break. (fingers crossed)

Answer (score 1):

You can make an alias or symlink to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit

Rightclick IOKit in finder. Make alias. Copy to both IOKit.framework/Versions/A/ and IOKit.framework/Versions and rename it to IOKit (and not IOKit Alias)

I used to be able to make a symlink, but it didn't work with latest xcode, but might be worth investigating:

```
sudo ln -sf /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit
```